# Custom Chat box Scrollbar display always bottom

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a custom chat box. I added overflow-y to scroll.
Now whenever I write something in the text box, it appears in the scrollbar window.
How can I make the scrollbar window show the last message which I write, in my case it always shows the top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Javascript you could try, assuming your div has the id `"scrolling"`

document.getElementById("scrolling").scrollTop = document.getElementById("scrolling").scrollHeight;

Where scrollTop is the number of pixels the object is scrolled and scrollHeigth is the total heigth of the content of the element including the content that is not visible due to overflow.

Important:

the above code should be executed every time that a new message appears in the chatbox, to do so it should be located in the right place into your script.

Source:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.scrollTop

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.scrollHeight

Another solution:

Maybe you could also do it by having an anchor (#idOfLastMessage) for the message, then using an iframe, instead of a div, which is pointing to www.yoursite.com/url-of-the-message-list#idOfLastMessage

Comment: Actually, at present my code looks like this:

        <script> var objDiv = document.getElementById("scrollbar");
        objDiv.100 = objDiv.200; 
        </script>
        <div id="scrollbar" style="height:200px;width:200px;overflow-y:scroll;overflow-position:bottom;" >
        <div id="messages" ></div>
        </div>  <br>
        <input id="chatinput" type="text" />

Comment: So you should try: `getElementById("scrollbar").scrollTop = getElementById("scrollbar").scrollHeight;` and this should go right before `</script>` let me know if it works.

Comment: I'm sorry! I forgot to add `document.` before `getElement`... see the working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mastazi/PXSgg/

Comment: Am I doing some mistake with the DOM, I am not able to do it.. You can check it in http://experimental.site44.com/
Its in the bottom side !!

Comment: Hey unfortunately I'm on mobile now, I can't access that URL with my iPhone (I get an error message saying that my browser is not supported), could you please just paste all your code in pastebin.com? It's easier than jsfiddle because you don't have to separate html, css and js, just copy and paste everything straight away. Or otherwise I'll have a look from my PC later.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20375/discussion-between-user9135-and-mastazi)

Comment: See the chat, I think I have found what was the problem in your code.